# How to truncate a string in groovy?

Tags: groovy, truncate

How to truncate string in groovy?

I used:

```
def c = truncate("abscd adfa dasfds ghisgirs fsdfgf", 10)
```

but getting error.

Answer (score 115):

The Groovy community has added a `take()` method which can be used for easy and **safe** string truncation.

Examples:

```
"abscd adfa dasfds ghisgirs fsdfgf".take(10)  //"abscd adfa"
"It's groovy, man".take(4)      //"It's"
"It's groovy, man".take(10000)  //"It's groovy, man" (no exception thrown)
```

There's also a corresponding `drop()` method:

```
"It's groovy, man".drop(15)         //"n"
"It's groovy, man".drop(5).take(6)  //"groovy"
```

Both `take()` and `drop()` are relative to the **start** of the string, as in *"take from the front"* and *"drop from the front"*.

Online Groovy console to run the examples:
https://ideone.com/zQD9Om — *(note: the UI is really bad)*

For additional information, see *"Add a take method to Collections, Iterators, Arrays"*:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-4865

Answer (score 11):

In Groovy, strings can be considered as ranges of characters. As a consequence, you can simply use range indexing features of Groovy and do `myString[startIndex..endIndex]`.

As an example,

```
"012345678901234567890123456789"[0..10]
```

outputs

```
"0123456789"
```

Comment: In addition ranges can also be negative with `-1` that means the last character of the string. So whenever you will need to truncate to the last part of a string you can easily do `string[-11..-1]`

Comment: this is not working when given "012345"[0..20]. I get the results in loop and some will have more and some dont have more characters. It should apply for the string which exceeds 20 chars. thanks

Comment: In your loop you would need to ensure you only substring if the string is greater than 10, for example, def s = it.size() > 10 ? it[0..10] : it

Comment: @john, yeah meanwhile i applied the same logic and works. thanks

Comment: Range indexing is nice, but if the string is shorter than 10 characters Groovy will throw StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 2):

we can simply use range indexing features of Groovy and do `someString[startIndex..endIndex].`

For example:

```
def str = "abcdefgh"
def outputTrunc = str[2..5]
print outputTrunc
```

Console:

```
"cde"
```

Comment: This only works for small limits. e.g. String bla = ha[0..2047] will always fail with StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.  looking for a better solution.

Comment: @JohnLittle: Your solution is [right below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15713996/3832970).

Answer (score 2):

To avoid word break you can make use of the *java.text.BreakIterator*. This will truncate a string to the closest word boundary after a number of characters.

**Example**

```
package com.example

import java.text.BreakIterator

class exampleClass { 

    private truncate( String content, int contentLength ) {     
        def result

        //Is content > than the contentLength?
        if(content.size() > contentLength) {  
           BreakIterator bi = BreakIterator.getWordInstance()
           bi.setText(content);
           def first_after = bi.following(contentLength)

           //Truncate
           result = content.substring(0, first_after) + "..."
        } else {
           result = content
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my helper functions to to solve this kinda problem. In many cases you'll probably want to truncate by-word rather than by-characters so I pasted the function for that as well.

```
public static String truncate(String self, int limit) {
    if (limit >= self.length())
        return self;

    return self.substring(0, limit);
}

public static String truncate(String self, int hardLimit, String nonWordPattern) {
    if (hardLimit >= self.length())
        return self;

    int softLimit = 0;
    Matcher matcher = compile(nonWordPattern, CASE_INSENSITIVE | UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher(self);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.start() > hardLimit)
            break;

        softLimit = matcher.start();
    }
    return truncate(self, softLimit);
}
```